# Send invites from guild 1 to guild 2

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am developing a way to generate a single use invite from a guild, we'll call it Guild One.

If were to do `!invite <@user>` in Guild 2, it would (again) send them the invite that the bot generated from guild 1 and send it to the <@user> via dms from guild 2. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

If you were to use the `!invite <@user>` command in Guild 1 it would send them an invite that the bot has created in Guild 2. It would then send the invite link to the mentioned user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

problem is if `@user` is not in guild1 (apparently not), u cannot access that user in guild2 since you dont have the user's attributes/id. You may need to enter user's id as text instead of `@user` like `!invite {USERID}`.

Also if `@user` is not in the bots cache (user has shown no activity in guild2 after bot was started) u need to `fetch` that `@user` into `guild.members`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch

but the user in guild2 can ask for invite link to join guild1

Comment: Amazing, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A way to accomplish this would be to create a `<Collection>` that stores the invite link mapped by the ID of the `<User>` that generated it, and then access this same `<Collection>` through the ID of the user that issues the command `!invite` in "Guild 2" to get the invite link URL.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks!